# Push Visual Studio Development website to internet

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to push my visual studio dev site to the internet for my boss to look over some work. I've used No-IP.org in the past and had no issues but I can't seem to get it working. I have opened the ports on my router but with no avail.

Are there any other ways to accomplish this task with minor configurations?

Cheers.

Comment: What iis server are you use ?

Comment: Local IIS7 for VS development.